# What is the purpose and convention of Windows.Forms.Form.HelpButton?

Tags: .net, winforms

I want to provide a simple help system to the users of my Windows forms app, and I am trying to decide on the best implementation. One user suggested making use of the Help Button provided in other similar apps.

I know that this particular property is used to enable the Help Button, but on a higher level, what does this provide an application developer? The example at the MSDN link below merely enables the button.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbutton.aspx

It seems to me that there must be a documentation methodology behind this. I could have a tooltip or something similar appear with a bit of information regarding the form being used, etc. I note that this is not available if the minimize and maximize buttons are visible, and so is only available in certain cases like fixed-size dialogs.

Comment: This is may be a better question for [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there to provide help to the user in a dialog.  Set the MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox properties to False to make the button visible.  Drop a HelpProvider on the form.  It adds three properties to every control.

The simplest way to use it is to set the HelpString property.  Try it and note what happens when you click on the help button and then on a control.  You'll see cursor change and the HelpString pop up in a tooltip after the click.  The more elaborate way to use it is through the HelpKeyword property, suitable when you authored a help file.  Which lets you automatically open a help window on a relevant help topic that matches the clicked control.

It doesn't get used too much anymore.  The restriction that it can only work in a dialog is a fairly awkward one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I knew there had to be more to it. It seems strange that the MSDN article about this doesn't mention HelpProvider.